# I need help on create a function to calculate UNIX timestamp to date format

Tags: timestamp, formula, autohotkey

I want to create a function, which calculates an UNIX Timestamp to a readable time format.

There's no existing function in Autohotkey to calculate it.
I know, that there is a way to calculate it by using a PHP Script, but I don't want to use this way.

My problem is, that I don't find a formula.

Is there anyone, who could give me food for thought?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about what the UNIX timestamp stands for, and the number of milliseconds in a minute/hour/day.

Comment: Check out this thread - http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/2486-code-to-convert-fromto-unix-timestamp/?p=402647

Answer (score 0):

This user-created AutoHotkey function should do what you require.

```
MsgBox % UnixTimeToDate(0, "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy")
MsgBox % UnixTimeToDate(10*86400, "HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy")
MsgBox % UnixTimeToDate(10*86400)
MsgBox % UnixTimeToDate(10*86400, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") ;same result as line above
Return

;where vSec is seconds since 1970-01-01
UnixTimeToDate(vSec, vFormat="")
{
vDate := 19700101000000
vDate += vSec, S
if !(vFormat = "")
FormatTime, vDate, %vDate%, %vFormat%
Return vDate
}
```